# LINQ SQL containsAll

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a list, that contains some packages IDs.

```
List<int> mustHavePackages = GetMustHavePackages();
```

And a database table

```
public class Table
{
 public int UserID;
 public int PackageID;
}
```

And I want to get from the database, those users that have **all** packages from the `mustHavePackages` list.

For now I have only achieved to get all users, that have *at least one* package from `mustHavePackages` list.

```
List<int> users =
(from t in db.Table
 where mustHavePackages.Contains(t.PackageID)
 select t.UserID).ToList();
```

And now I'm looking for something like ContainsAll or similar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var temp=
(from t in db.Table
 group t by t.UserId into g
 select new {UserId = g.Key, PackageIds = g.Select(gg=>gg.PackageId)}).ToList();

var users = (from t in temp
            where !mustHavePackages.Except(t.PackageIds).Any()
            select t.UserId).ToList();
```

Something like this perhaps. You can add the 2nd part in the first part as well to make one call and not bring extra data, this is to show you the breakdown.

Comment: Thank you, this code works almost as expected, but I forgot to mention, that those users that have all packages from the mustHavePackages list and more (lets say optional packages), should be selected too. This code selects all users, that have exactly the same packages.

Comment: Updated the code to handle that, you can reverse the .Except